# Unable to upload mutiple image using kartik fileinput in yii2

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to upload multiple files using drag and drop functionality. I got the array while click on save() but it is unable to upload it throws:

> Call to a member function SaveAs() on array

_form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use backend\models\Users;
use yii\helpers\Arrayhelper;
use kartik\file\FileInput;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\Url;

?>

<div class="album-form">

     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
            'id' => $model->formName(),
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,

        ]); ?>

<?php  echo FileInput::widget([
            'name' => 'albummediaFile[]',
            'options'=>[
                'multiple'=>true,
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'maxFileCount' => 10,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'maxFileSize'=>2000,
                'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png','jpeg'],
            ]
        ]);
    ?>
```

AlbumController.php(controller)

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Album();
        $modelalbummedia = new Albummedia(); 


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


          $modelalbummedia->albummediaFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($modelalbummedia, 'albummediaFile');

                    if ($modelalbummedia->upload()) {

                        return;
                    }
                      $modelalbummedia->save();
                    }


            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->albumID]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelalbummedia' => $modelalbummedia,
                ]);
            }

    }
```

Albummedia.php(Model)

```
public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            foreach ($this->albummediaFile as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/Album_Media/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

                $model->albummediaFile = $_FILES['albummediaFile']; **Not getting file name here.
            }
            return true;
       } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['albummediaFile']['name']);$i++){
```

to:

```
foreach($modelalbummedia->albummediaFile as $file) {
```

And inside the loop use `$file` instead of `$modelalbummedia->albummediaFile`

Copy&paste code:

```
    $modelalbummedia->albummediaFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($modelalbummedia, 'albummediaFile');
    if($modelalbummedia->albummediaFile){
        foreach($modelalbummedia->albummediaFile as $file){
            $imagepath = 'uploads/Album_Media/';
            $random_value = rand(000,999).time();
            $file->SaveAs($imagepath.$random_value.$file->baseName);
            $file = $random_value.$file->baseName;
        }
      $modelalbummedia->save();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my code as above see. Now it show me error: **Undefined offset: 0**

Comment: First of all, u still use `$modelalbummedia->albummediaFile` inside loop. Second: `if($_FILES['albummediaFile']['name'][0] != ""){` this line throws exception, cause u didnt send any files. Change it to `if($modelalbummedia->albummediaFile) {` and stop using `$_FILES` directly.

Comment: @Akkie updated answer, please read it carefully, dont just paste and forget.

Comment: right now get nothing in an array `$modelalbummedia->albummediaFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($modelalbummedia, 'albummediaFile');`

Comment: Cause u did not send the file or did it wrong. Update question with view code.

Comment: Where is ActiveForm declaration in view?

Comment: I see now, its in your `FileInput` config. U set `'uploadUrl'` param to `Url::to(['uploads/Album_Media']),`, so it uploads files to this url by ajax. Remove this line to upload it without using ajax.

Comment: okk i have remove that line, but it removes drag and drop functinality and while uploading image it returns nothing in an array. I have to upload image with drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Okay, i see from your answers u begin beautiful adventure with Yii2. Please read documentation how to upload files here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html   AND read about FileInput widget here: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput . Unfortunately we wont write code for u here.

Comment: I got the answer as you mentioned above given link but i am using two different model and now I do not get the name of file while making entry in database.

Comment: You don't even try to understand code u write. U just go copy&paste and 'it should work!'. No, it wont work. ` $_FILES['albummediaFile'];` is array of files, not filename, you dont have `$model` variable in your `upload()` function but ure using it, and variable representing of current file in loop is `$file`. DONT USE `$_FILES` directly as i said before. `$file->baseName` holds your filename. Please read docs again.